# mySQL trigger not firing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 4 columns [year, v_num, t_num, percentage], I'm trying to populate percentage with v_num/t_num*100. The data is already in the table but the percentage column is NULL. I created an AFTER INSERT trigger to populate the column but it's not working. Does anyone have any suggestions?

TRIGGER

```
 DELIMITER |

CREATE DEFINER = 'XXX' TRIGGER percentAfterUp
AFTER INSERT
ON `table`
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN 

UPDATE `table` SET percentage = v_num/t_num*100;


END|

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Nothing is happening

Comment: Just calculate the value when you need it instead of adding duplicate data in your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set a value in a row, do it with a *before* insert trigger, not an *after* insert trigger:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE DEFINER = 'XXX' TRIGGER percentAfterUp
BEFORE INSERT ON `table` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    SET new.percentage = (new.v_num / new.t_num) * 100;
END|

DELIMITER ;
```

If you actually want to update all the rows, don't use a trigger, just an `update` statement:

```
UPDATE `table`
    SET percentage = (v_num/t_num)*100;
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. Don't I have to use AFTER INSERT if the data in other columns is already populated. If not, when would someone use AFTER INSERT?

Comment: @ybce . . . You might use an `AFTER INSERT` to put the record in an archive table.  That way, there are not two transactions taking place at the same time.  And, how did the answer not work?  Do note that this is an `insert` trigger not an `update` trigger so it only takes effect when new data is inserted.

Comment: I knew I could use this but I wanted it to be automated since I'll be adding more data to the table later.